# How to fix this code so as to echo back the output and not undefined? JSONP, PHP, mySQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am trying to show some data using jsonp and jquery, however I am missing something.

On the php file, I save into mysql, and I get from the database a field to send it back through the `$back` variable.

After this, I callback this and echo the `$back` I got from the DB.

In client side I get `undefined` . What am I missing here?

```
    function showPopup(data) {
        setTimeout(function () {
    alert(data);
    }, 1000);

    }


function group(){
      $.getJSON("http://domain.comhandler.php?type=group&callback=i&cookie="+ y, showPopup());
}
```

**server side**

```
echo $callback . "(" . json_encode($back)  . ")";
```

Answer (score 1):

Your not calling your call back correctly you can use

```
 $.getJSON("http://domain.comhandler.php?type=group&callback=i&cookie="+ y, showPopup);
```

note I have removed the `()`

or

```
 $.getJSON("http://domain.comhandler.php?type=group&callback=i&cookie="+ y, function(data){ showPopup(data); } );
```

Comment: I cant get the alert popup too

Comment: In the Inspect element of chrome I get a response i("some html code I placed")

Comment: Shall I have a callback function i somewhere?